# Local Notifications are not showing in android 13

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-permissions, user-permissions, android-13

I have an app which uses notifications and everything is working fine below android 12 but on android 13 doesn't show the notifications. I have also added notification permissions but I can't figure out what is wrong any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Here is my code

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

AlarmReceiver.kt

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

private val CHANNEL_ID = "1"
private val CHANNEL_NAME = "Notifications"

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        channel.description = context!!.getString(R.string.app_name)
        channel.enableLights(true)
        channel.enableVibration(true)
        channel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
        channel.setShowBadge(true)
        channel.lockscreenVisibility = NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    val quote = runBlocking {
        generateQuoteNotification(context!!)
    }
    // Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
    val newIntent =  Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(Constants.STRING_EXTRA_INCOMING_FRAGMENT, Constants.ACTIVITY_NOTIFICATION)
        putExtra(Constants.STRING_EXTRA_QUOTE, quote)
    }

    // Create the TaskStackBuilder
    val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(context).run {
        // Add the intent, which inflates the back stack
        addNextIntentWithParentStack(newIntent)
        // Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    }

    // Build Notification
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
        .setColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.teal_700,null))
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(quote)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) // On Notification Click Goto DetailActivity
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
        // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context.applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            context.showToast("Please grant Notification permission from App Settings")
            return
        }
        notify(1, builder.build())
    }
}

private suspend fun generateQuoteNotification(context: Context):
        String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).quoteDao()
    db.generateNotification().quote
}
}
```

And here is my MainActivity.kt

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

    checkNotificationPermission()
    createNotification()


    drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
    val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController

    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

}


private fun checkNotificationPermission() {
    // Sets up permissions request launcher.
    val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your app.
            createNotification()
            showToast("permission is granted -- requestPermissionLauncher")
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                "Please grant Notification permission from App Settings",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    }

    when {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
            Log.e(TAG, "User accepted the notifications!")
            createNotification()
        }
        shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) -> {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                "The user denied the notifications ):",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
            )
                .setAction("Settings") {
                    val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    val uri: Uri =
                        Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
                    intent.data = uri
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                .show()
        }
        else -> {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
        }
    }
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}


private fun createNotification() {

    val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
        0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    val alarms = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

    val  calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    // val  now = Calendar.getInstance()

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5)

//            if (now.after(calendar)) {
//                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
//            }

    alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent)

}
```

}

P.S I don't have a physical device to test on so i'm using emulator